# Multiple SQL Standard Instances on 4 Processor/32-core Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

We have a large 4 processor/32-core server with 192GB of memory available in the data center and over twenty small SQL Standard databases to consolidate.   They are a mix of SQL 2012 and 2008 R2 for 3rd-party apps.

Is there any issue with simply installing two instances of SQL Standard on the server - one for 2012 and one for 2008 R2 ?  Each instance will use up to 64GB out of the 192GB and 16 cores.  If we did this with Enterprise, the licensing would be a fortune and the Enterprise features are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

I run multiple instances of 2008 on the same server in production, and versions of 2008 and 2005 on the same server in QA for testing.  Each instance is named and assigned a specific port.   This hasn't caused any problems.

It doesn't look like this would cause a problem with 2012;  it looks like this is fully supported.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694.aspx